# Extracting attribute value in XML using MOXy

Tags: xml, moxy

Does anyone know how I can map the value of an attribute to a field. Say the value of tag lang, which is "sw" to a field in a class

```
<book category="cooking">
        <title lang="sw">Vegetarian</title>
        <year>2008</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <authors>
            <author>Tichaona</author>
            <author>Ngodza</author>
        </authors>
    </book>

......
......
......

<book category="Huffman Coding">
        <title lang="en">Encryption</title>
        <year>2000</year>
        <price>45.00</price>
        <authors>
            <author>Ruvimbo</author>
        </authors>
    </book>
```

I want to be able to put the value in attribute lang to a field using MOXy extension. More along the lines of

```
@XmlPath("title/@lang")
private String language;
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Moxy set up correctly, I think the issue you would have with your example is that the Xpath `"title/@lang"` would not actually resolve to the attribute you are wanting.

Something like `//title/@lang` should do the trick for picking the value of the lang attribute.

Comment: Thanks Christy, I wonder why it needs 2 forward slashes. I will try that.

Comment: A single forward slash is for the root, double means it will search elements that aren't just direct children. I'm not actually 100% sure if you need those using Moxy, I would have assumed that the path will be relative to the root of the class being marshalled